# How to convert shapefiles into ascii grid .asc in QGIS?

Tags: convert, dem, export, ascii, esri-ascii-raster

I downloaded multiple zips that cover a small island from the Rhode Island Geographic Information System webpage, specifically the geographic files that make up Block Island.

Here's the source: http://www.edc.uri.edu/rigis/data/download/2011USGS/muni.aspx?ID=22

I'm trying to convert these files into .asc. From what little information I managed to find online I must make a the vector into a raster and make it a  point/grid image and then save it as a .asc

I can get the point style raster image but I'm unable to save/export as the.asc.

Does anyone know how to do it? I also have geotiff and grass gis if it helps the process.

Comment: Why don't you use the DEM file they provide? The shapefiles don't contain more information.